# Google speech to text api (reading from GCS broken)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

As it says in the title, I can't get the s2t API to work with gcs.

When working with local <1m files, it works well, but when I provide it a gcs link (be it of the same short file or a longer one) I get bad results. I either get nothing, or just a very small portion of the file transcribed (~5 words out of a 2 minute speech).

Is there some gotcha that I'm not aware of, or is it a known bug that I just couldn't find on the internet? Here is the code used (google's own example in js):

```
  const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient();
  const gcsUri = `gs://myBucket/${toRec}`;
  const encoding = 'AMR';
  const sampleRateHertz = 8000;
  const languageCode = 'sr-RS';

  const config = {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
  };

  const audio = {
    uri: gcsUri,
  };

  const request = {
    config: config,
    audio: audio,
  };

  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
```

Comment: Maybe you are reaching some quota. I also did not found any issue related to this code.

Comment: @AndieVanille It is a fresh account with billing enabled. Less than 60 minutes (the first 60 minutes are free every month) were used. The same sound file works well when uploaded outside of gcs.

Comment: Can you post the [response](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.speech.v1#longrunningrecognizeresponse) from the API?

Comment: @IsaacMiliani Both local and gcs respond with two transcriptions (alternatives). I provided the same file, but the gcs transcription is far inferior. Gcs one has 0.8605201840400696 and 0.4814569354057312 confidences, and the local one has 0.8711020946502686 and 0.7969886660575867.

Comment: It's strange, I would say try to upgrade your client libraries and if the issue persists [create an issue in the public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=451645&template=0)